# Not able to install numpy or nltk python-modules

Tags: python, windows, numpy, nltk

I am having a strange issue installing numpy or nltk python-modules in my windows-7 machine. I have successfully installed Python 2.7.12 but I get this error when I type `pip install numpy` as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KAI0.png). I have also included the directory of `pip.exe` in the `PATH`. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you :)

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: @alvas Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing such these things in windows are sometime difficult, specially for someone new to python packages(also for some experts!)

Try to use Anaconda for windows: https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows
This install a python for you and many requirement packages(e.g Numpy, Scipy, Scikit and many more)

You can use older version of Anaconda, for python2.x if you want strictly python2.x

---

An alternative way is to download Numpy from github and then install it as a python package, that contain setup.py file

```
python setup.py install
```

Or you can download Numpy wheel package, then install it localy with pip